# creating my own login form django

Tags: python, django

Been looking for 2 days now, I simply need to create my own login form .. I need to create the form in **forms.py** then connect to a view in **views.py** and call it from an URL in **urls.py** and all use my custom user model as backend

here are my **models.py** that contains user model :

```
class UserModelManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, pseudo):
        user = self.model()
        user.name = name
        user.email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        '''
        Used for: python manage.py createsuperuser
        '''
        user = self.model()
        user.name = 'admin-yeah'
        user.email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()

        return user


class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ## Personnal fields.
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ## [...]

    ## Django manage fields.
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['email', 'name']

    objects = UserModelManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name[:2].upper()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: And where are you stuck? What have you done so far?

Comment: @DanielRoseman -  Created the custom login model, and am using the built-in login system by adding `auth_views.login` to **urls.py** then it auto getting the data from `templates/registartion/login.html'`, that what I need to change

Comment: *What* do you need to change?

Comment: @DanielRoseman need to use my own form..need to create a form in **forms.py** that contains `['email', 'password'] fields then create a view in **views.py** that works with the login (authenticating form) which I don't know how to do!

Comment: But why? You just said you were using the built in ones.

Comment: Becuase I need to get cleaned email when a user enters it in login form .. I need it to be sent as.lower() to get the whole email in lower case and compare with the saved one which is saved as lowercase too, as I found the best way to do that is to add `data = self.cleaned_data['email']` then `return data.lower()` and that have to be done inside the **forms.py** , can't be done in the default login

Comment: But that's what the default form will do, because you set USERNAME_FIELD to 'email'.

Comment: but it not converting it to lower case, when user signup it is saved as test@gmail.com ( all lower case ).. but when the user logs in if he typed (Test@gmail.com) it returns an error ( wrong email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that all you want to do is convert the entered email address to lower case. You can do this by subclassing the auth firm and adding a clean method for the field:

```
class EmailAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean_username(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["username"].lower()
```

And now use this in the view via urls.py.

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=EmailAuthForm), name="login")
```

Comment: `File "F:\django\fostania\fostania\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView(authentication_form=EmailAuthForm), name='login'),
  File "C:\Users\LiTo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

Comment: Raised the error mentioned in the past comment ^^^^

Comment: `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` another error, but the solution is getting closer

Comment: Sorry again, don't know what I was thinking. Try now.

Comment: ok no syntax or type errors now, but it still says the wrong email when I try to log on with one letter on uppercase, as the saved data in DB is the whole email as lowercase

Comment: Maybe try using "username": `def clean_username(self): return self.cleaned_data["username"].lower()`

Comment: Great ,, it works ,, kindly edit the answer so i mark as the right answer